# Good design for having an ActivityIndicator across entire app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have the need for an activity indicator view in my app when different views are loading and when data is being retrieved.  The problem is the mainVC (where I would place the indicator) is not always aware of when processing is happening so it can start the indicator but it cannot stop it.

e.g.  the mainVC loads and then programatically adds a new VC - this VC in turn asks a model to retrieve - it displays data etc.  So this newly added VC actually knows when processing is finished and it does not have access to the indicator view (although the indicator is visible at the top).

I was thinking of using notifications - is this the best way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the brilliant `MBProgressHUD` library:

https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

It's a very simple set of classes you can use to display loading and progress views that can be accessed by all view controllers in your app. Basically, you can set it up in your app delegate and add it to your app window.

Every view controller can then access the progress view from the delegate and show/hide it when required. It comes with an example project and code - it's very easy to use and customise.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are one half of the solution. You have to combine them with a persistent object so that you can also get the current state at all times. E.g., when a view controller is about to appear, it needs to read the initial "downloading" state from somewhere, because the VC might have been created after the "start" or "end" notification was sent.

Then, while the VC is alive, it can simply respond to notifications to update the indicator.

This design is particulary important for views, which run the risk of getting unloaded/reloaded all the time.

Comment: No idea what you just said sorry

Comment: You cannot depend on notifications alone. You also need to have some way of finding out if the indicator should be active at a certain time.